# Apps script: Get html form values inputted into a web app

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am working on a script that requires html form data to be inputted to a web app, I then want to be able to process that form data and put it on a google sheet. The thing is I can't seem to do that. Here is my code:

Index.html

```
<form id="Form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); 
google.script.run.getData(this)">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Code.gs

```
function getData(data) {
    var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Logs');
    sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(data.name);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that your your `data` doesn't have a `name` member/key. Hence, you are writing a `null` value in your current cell which will result to an empty cell value.

### Sample Code:

```js
function getData(data) {
  Logger.log(data)
  Logger.log(data.name)
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Logs');
  sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(data.firstname);
}
```

### Execution Logs:

[image]

### Output:

[image]

- In this example, my current active cell is in `A1`

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) for a practical example.
In your case, you have a form which you submit. In that case the form does not know which is the active cell. Therefore you should replace `getCurrentCell()`with `getRange()` or `appendRow()`

**Reference**

- [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) - You could do this `appendRow([formObject.name])`
- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) - Paired with `getLastRow()`, you can then set the value in it